# Issues with correctly writing my c++ Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall

OBJECTS = foo.o bar.o baz.o

main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX)

testBuild: main
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Itest/catch/catch.hpp -o test/TestCase $(OBJECTS) test/TestCase.cpp

test: clean testBuild
    test/TestCase --success

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.gch main test/TestCase
```

I'm trying to get my make file written, but for some reason I keep getting an error:

```
rm -f *.o *.gch main test/TestCase
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.o', needed by 'main'.  Stop.
```

I can't see what I'm missing and could use some assistance. I have 3 .hpp class files, a .cpp isn't being created for each file at all instead I am using a TestCase.cpp and catch.hpp file. I've tried several different variations of the above Makefile, but have yet to get a working form. let me know if there is any other information you need. The TestCase.cpp is below:

```
// Let Catch provide main():
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include <vector>
#include "catch/catch.hpp"
#include "../foo.hpp"
#include "../bar.hpp"
#include "../baz.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Test Classes. PASS.")
{
    REQUIRE (Foo::GetMagicNumber() == 12);

    Bar b = Bar("Hello");
    REQUIRE (b.GetString() == "Hello");

    Baz *baz = new Baz(90.0 / 9);
    REQUIRE ((baz->GetValue() > 9.999 && baz->GetValue() < 10.0001));
}

// Compile & run:
// make clean test
```

Comment: Your makefile doesn't have any rules to make any of your object files.  Also the rule for main doesn't actually do anything.  It just calls `g++` with no arguments.  Also, the `vim` tag doesn't seem to serve any purpose for this question.

Comment: Do you know how to compile your code manually, i.e. without a makefile?

Comment: In case your goal is not to learn `makefile`, but just to use those, I recommend you to use https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of explicit rule to make `foo.o`, make will try implicit pattern rules to try to build it for you (there are few extra possible step omitted for simplicity) and when it runs out of ideas, it will fail and display the error message you're seeing.

In other words. In your case make could neither find `foo.o` nor could it build. It would have likely searched for `foo.c`, `foo.cpp`, `foo.C`, ... You can get a complete list by running `make` with `--debug=i`.

You must either make sure that all sources are available for all files expected to link main (i.e. for which `$(OBJECTS)` object files can be produced). Or reduce that list to actually available and needed list of files.

Also please note, once you clear this hurdle, your make file will not link your executable because:

```
main: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX)
```

Once all the prerequisites are available and `main` can be built, it will just run `g++` and fail, because no inputs are specified, at minimum you likely want to say something like:

```
main: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $+
```

To fire up `g++` using target name (`main`) for output and all prerequisites (`$(OBJECTS)`) as inputs.